# What is a "Bogey Competition"?

Tags: terminology, golf

In my golf diary, there's a "Bogey Competition" to be held next weekend. What is a "Bogey Competition"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The competition is played hole by hole. If a player shoots a birdie or better he wins that hole and marks it with a **+**. If a player shoots a bogey or worse he loses the hole and marks it down with a **-**. A player *halves* the hole if they shoot par and this is marked with a **0**. The lost holes are subtracted from the won holes to give a final score.

Example...

- Hole 1 - Par 3

You shoot a Par. Result **0**

- Hole 2 - Par 5

You shoot a 3. Result **+**

- Hole 3 - Par 4

You shoot an 8. Result **-**

- Hole 4 - Par 6

You shoot an 4. Result **+**

**End Result**: 0, +, -, + = **+1**

Answer (score 4):

In Ireland we call this format V-Par because you are completing against (versus) par.

It is essentially the same as playing match play against par on every hole. Like in match play there are only three outcomes for each hole, (Win, Halve, Loss).

Unlike match play you must play all 18 holes even if you are for example 3 up with 2 holes left. So if you beat par on 6 holes, lost on 4 holes and halved the other 8 your total score would be 2 up.